# How to upload a photo to profile of fans with their name ?

Tags: facebook, upload

Like this app http://www.facebook.com/pages/Welcher-Simpsons-Charackter-bist-du/143753942375692?sk=app_197801216980659
help me ...

Answer (score 0):

sample code for you

```
<?php
          // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
          // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
          require_once('src/facebook.php');
        $config=array();
        $config['appid']='****';
        $config['secret']='*********';
        $config['appurl']='http://apps.facebook.com/YOUR APP/';
          $configsdk = array(
            'appId' => $config['appid'],
            'secret' => $config['secret'],
            'fileUpload' => TRUE, // optional
          );

          $facebook = new Facebook($configsdk);
          $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

        if(empty($user_id)){
            $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
               . $GLOBALS['config']['appid'] . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($config['appurl']).'&scope=publish_stream';
            echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$dialog_url ."' </script>");
            break;
        }
              // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
              // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
              try {
                $user=$facebook->api('me','GET');
              } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e->getType());
                error_log($e->getMessage());
              }  
        $src['0']='http://techsinter.com/apps/picbackg.jpg';
        $iTmp2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($src['0']);
        $iOut = imagecreatetruecolor ("740","680") ;
        @imagecopy ($iOut,$iTmp2,0,0,0,0,imagesx($iTmp2),imagesy($iTmp2));
        @imagedestroy ($iTmp2); 
        $white = imagecolorallocate($iOut, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
        // Path to our ttf font file
        $font_file = './arial.ttf';
        // Draw the text 'PHP Manual' using font size 13
        $photo=time().'.png';
        imagefttext($iOut, 13, 0, 300, 40, $white, $font_file, $user['name']);
        imagepng($iOut,$photo);
     $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
                                         'source' => '@' . $photo,
                                         'message' => 'Hello',
                                         )
                                      );
    unlink($photo);
      ?>
```

---

well that app is getting users permission to publish & after getting this permissions uploading a photo from a page is exactly like uploading a photo from an app
at first you must get user's name from api merge user's name & a photo 
upload it to users profile Read here :

Upload a photo to a User's profile

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Comment: i will Update my post & put full code for you in PHP ok ?
are you php programmer ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this codes. But now how to url of image to post in profile of fans.

Comment: $photo = './mypic.png'; // Path to the photo on the local filesystem

Comment: how to get the url $photo = './mypic.png'; <- here image

Comment: if you want to upload it:
if your code is here example.com/index.php
change two last lines 
`header ("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($iOut,NULL);`
to this 
`$time=time();
    imagepng($iOut,$time.'.png');`
& then make image link like this 
`$photo='http://example.com'.$time.'.jpg'`
upload the image & then 
unlink the image 
if your app is going to have many users change $time from `$time=time() to $time=time()+microtime()`

Comment: $photo='http://example.com'.$time.'.jpg' --- example.com (link of image ) ? because doesn't work

Comment: example.com is the place you uploaded image

Comment: $photo='http://example.com'.$time.'.jpg' this code doesn't work . Can you gice me another code , because a try many times and this code dont work

Comment: i will check it up , i'm busy :)

Comment: Something was wrong in my code ,code edited , i tested this one all you need is setting `$config`

Comment: Thanks you , the codes works. but is it possible that two people use the same app and view different photo ?

Comment: Yes,its possible 
do this 
`$src['0']='http://techsinter.com/apps/picbackg.jpg';
 $src['1']='http://techsinter.com/apps/picbackg1.jpg';
$src['2']='http://techsinter.com/apps/picbackg2.jpg';
$rand=rand(0,2);
$iTmp2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($src[$rand]);`

Comment: click on Ask question for new questions , next it must be because you are doing something against facebook  platform privacy is your app uploading without asking user ?